# In Realm, Is there any way to make a custom array of database rows that I can still Query?

Tags: ios, realm

If I need to custom build a list of database rows because I can not do it with a query (I need to correlate it with external data), is there anyway to make it so the resulting RLMArray is able to be queried?

When I run the following line:

```
return [all_matches objectsWhere:@"rootGUID == ''"];
```

I get the following exception:

**This method can only be called on RLMArray instances retrieved from an RLMRealm**

The only thing I can think of is to have an empty column so I can manually flag it, but that seems a bit outrageous.

Answer (score 0):

I found a decent way around this. Instead of actually collecting instances in a RLMArray, I collected their primary key within an NSArray. Then, when I want a RLMResult for the specific values I found, I call.

```
[MyRealmTable objectsWhere:@"PrimaryKey IN %@", Collected_Key_Array];
```